# Vuetify: How to add an avatar or an icon to the bottom of a navigation drawer

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a sidebar,using Vuetify, where there will be some common actions on the top and the user avatar will be on the bottom.

I'm using `v-navigation-drawer` and so far I've come up with this:

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer 
        app 
        permanent
        mini-variant="true"
        class="cyan lighten-3"
    >
        <v-list>
            <!-- Timeline action -->
            <v-list-tile> 
                <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-btn
                        flat
                        exact
                        icon 
                        color="white"
                    >     
                        <v-icon>timeline</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>              
                </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
            <!-- Sms action -->
            <v-list-tile> 
                <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-btn
                        flat
                        exact
                        icon 
                        color="white"
                    >     
                        <v-icon>sms</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>              
                </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
            <!-- Calendar action -->
            <v-list-tile> 
                <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-btn
                        flat
                        exact
                        icon 
                        color="white"
                    >     
                        <v-icon>calendar_today</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>              
                </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
            <!-- Settings Action -->
            <v-list-tile> 
                <v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-btn
                        flat
                        exact
                        icon
                        color="white"
                    >     
                        <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>              
                </v-list-tile-action>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <!--This should be the avatar but I used a btn for demo purposes-->
        <v-btn
            flat
            exact
            icon
            bottom
            color="red"
        >     
            <v-icon>timeline</v-icon>
        </v-btn>              

    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
<!-- <script> and <style> follow after this-->
```

So as you can see after my `v-list` I've utilized a `v-divider` and placed the icon (or avatar) below.

The problem is that I cannot move this all the way to the bottom of the `v-navigation-drawer`. I tried using `v-flex` around the `v-list` and the final `v-btn` but to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a slot inside your navigation drawer component like so :

```html
<template v-slot:append>
    <div class="pa-2">
       <v-btn block>Logout</v-btn>
    </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  They should make this clearer in the docs.

Comment: Great answer. And it is now in the docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#combined-drawer). Remember you can [edit that page Github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/pages/en/components/navigation-drawers.md)

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your nav list and avatar in a `v-layout` with the `justify-space-between`, `column` and `fill-height` props:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true
  })
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.22/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


<v-app id="app">
  <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" fixed app>
    <v-layout fill-height column justify-space-between>
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>home</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>contact_mail</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Contact</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
      <v-avatar color="red">
        <v-icon dark>account_circle</v-icon>
      </v-avatar>
    </v-layout>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark fixed app>
    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid fill-height>
      <v-layout justify-center align-center>
        <v-flex text-xs-center>

        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

Comment: This solution is ideal. The prepend/append in the docs (and other answers) causes strange layout issues that this avoids.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `justify-end` to the button and wrapping list and btn in `v-layout` with `column` and `fill-height` should do the work for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daMXqp?editors=1000

```
  <v-layout align-center justify-space-between column fill-height>
    <v-list>
      ...
    </v-list>
    <v-btn
           justify-end
           flat
           exact
           icon
           color="green"
           ><v-icon>dashboard</v-icon></v-btn> 
  </v-layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't make the icon go all the way down. You can see yourself, if you expand the output panel of your codepen.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm trying to find another solution.

Comment: [This](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#layout-playground) helped me find a working solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: Codepen link seems broken ("ReferenceError: Vue is not defined ")

Answer (score 0):

It seems that just adding `fill-height` to the `v-layout` will fill the height of the element, so any other element you add next will be forced to be at the bottom.